# Javascript/jQuery: Convert key combo to string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I'm looking for an existing Javascript library, or even better, a jQuery plugin, which detects a key combo and outputs the corresponding string (for example, "ctrl+shift+f"). This is to allow a user to configure a key combo for a Google Chrome plugin. The preferences behavior for BetterTouchTool ( http://www.boastr.de/ ) is a good example of what I'm talking about. Has anyone come across something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I even asked this question! After many months, I've written a plugin myself that does exactly this =)

http://suan.github.com/jquery-keycombinator/

Answer (score 0):

I think something of this kind might help:

```
document.onkeydown = KeyDownHandler;
document.onkeyup = KeyUpHandler;
var CTRL = false;      
var SHIFT = false;     
var ALT = false;
var CHAR_CODE = -1;

function KeyDownHandler(e) {
    var x = '';
    if (document.all) {
        var evnt = window.event;
        x = evnt.keyCode;
    }
    else {
        x = e.keyCode;
    }
    DetectKeys(x, true);
    DoSometing();
}

function KeyUpHandler(e) {
    var x = '';
    if (document.all) {
        var evnt = window.event;
        x = evnt.keyCode;
    }
    else {
        x = e.keyCode;
    }
    DetectKeys(x, false);
    DoSometing();

}
function DetectKeys(KeyCode, IsKeyDown) {
    if (KeyCode == '16') {
        SHIFT = IsKeyDown;
    }
    else if (KeyCode == '17') {
        CTRL = IsKeyDown;
    }
    else if (KeyCode == '18') {
        ALT = IsKeyDown;
    }
    else {
        if(IsKeyDown)
            CHAR_CODE = KeyCode;
        else
            CHAR_CODE = -1;
    }
}

function DoSometing() {
    //check for keys here
}
```

I hope it'll be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    alert(
        (e.ctrlKey ? 'ctrl+' : '') +
        (e.altKey ? 'alt+' : '') +
        (e.shiftKey ? 'shift+' : '') +
        String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase()
    );
});
```

This will register the keys; not sure how you're going to block the ctrl/alt keys from getting interpreted though.

browser support: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html